# How can I proxy traffic of macOS Mojave APPS using Burp Suite?

Tags: appsec, proxy, burp-suite, http-proxy

If I do a web search for proxying macOS apps using Burp Suite, I don't get any useful info. Instead, I get dozens of results talking about how to proxy *iOS or Android apps*. I am talking about *desktop apps*. On macOS, I've followed the below steps:

1. Downloaded and installed Burp Suite (Note it's been installed, as I'm not a new Burp Suite user)
2. Set the proxy up on 127.0.0.1:8080
3. Installed the Burp CA as Trusted Root
4. Went to macOS System Preferences -> Network -> Proxies and configured HTTP and HTTPS to proxy through 127.0.0.1:8080 .

After step 4, no apps are able to communicate with the web at all. When I follow this exact same process on my Windows machine, all apps are now proxied properly. I'm not sure what extra step is needed on macOS to achieve proxying of various applications which communicate on HTTP. Again, I am NOT talking about a web browser, I am talking about non-browser apps.

What else I've tried:

1. "Invisible Proxy" setting on my listener
2. Editing my macOS hosts file so that it re-routes traffic to the domains that the app reaches out to to 127.0.0.1, then setting up listeners in Burp on 127.0.0.1:80 and 127.0.0.1:443

None of these options work. In the last case directly above, Burp won't let me "enable" the listeners on 80 and 443. However, I don't have to do any of this (add any items to hosts file or set up other listeners other than 8080) on Windows. Also Charles Proxy on my macOS *does* in fact intercept ALL app traffic, so I know it's possible... But Charles does something behind the scenes that I can't seem to get Burp to do.